# vuejs filter is not a function error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a very basic array:

```
specialityTest: [{person:'nurse', text:'text1'}, 
{person:'nurse', text:'text1'}, 
{person:'physician', text:'text1'}, 
{person:'physician', text:'text1'}]
```

I'm trying to filter this using basic filter function:

```
      this.specialityTest.filter((person) => {
        return (person =="physician")
      })
```

and then copy filtered array:

```
  methods: {
   seedSpeciality(){
      this.nurseListSpeciality2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.specialityTest.filter(
      (person) => {
        return (person =="physician")
      })))
  },
 }
```

and this is not working for me... I've got error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.specialityTest.filter is not a function 
 at VueComponent.seedSpeciality (AddOfferDialog.vue?f4fc:1771)
    at VueComponent.boundFn [as seedSpeciality]`.

What am I doing wrong here?

edit:
I run this function from api call:

```
  fetchSpecialityArray(){
    this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/speciality')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => this.specialityTest = result).then(this.seedSpeciality.bind(this))
  },
```

Comment: Do a `console.log(this.specialityTest)` to see if it's what you expect _(may be `undefined`)_. Also, your filter condition should be `person.person === "physician"`

Comment: `console.log(this.specialityTest)` gives the correct array of 90 elements. changing filter conditions to `person.person` is not changing the error

Comment: Your error seems to indicate that you're calling the method in a Promise. Is this the case? If so, `this` may not be correctly binding and you may need to explicitly bind the value. Alternatively, you can store `this` inside a variable accessible via closure and then use that variable instead.

Comment: @B.Fleming this could be the case - see my edit

Comment: @blex correct. console.log in seedSpeciality shows correct array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For me it works fine.Take a look:

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="filter">Filter</button>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    specialityTest: [
      {person:'nurse', text:'text1'}, 
      {person:'nurse', text:'text1'}, 
      {person:'physician', text:'text1'}, 
      {person:'physician', text:'text1'}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    filter() {
        let filtered = this.specialityTest.filter((el) => {
        return (el.person =="physician")
      })
      console.log(filtered)
    }
  }
})
```

*You are looping through array of object with filter function so in each loop you get the object.So if you use el.person == "physician" it will work fine*

Take a look to [my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/eywraw8t/33626/)

Comment: When you use the function filter,you are looping through array of objects.so in each loop you are getting the object.So you cannot use person == "physician",but if you want person.person == "physician".Try my code it works fine

Comment: this is not solving the error - see updated question. Maybe because I call this function in a Promise could be the case

Comment: to understand the question.You want to filter the specialityTest property when you get response from backend?I am not clear where is the problem but obviously my response is right when you use filter function

Comment: no doubt that your code is correct, I've changed my code, but gets the same error. I don't know the case :/

Comment: Please give a clear description of your problem.What i am understanding is that you get from api data that will fill the specialityTest property.Then you want to filter this property.Am i right?

Comment: correct. I run console.log(this.specialityTest) inside seedSpeciality() function and this gives me correct array to filter

Comment: So where is the problem?

Comment: I've got an error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.specialityTest.filter is not a function`

Comment: Try in seedsSpeciality to replace this: this.nurseListSpeciality2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.specialityTest.filter(
      (person) => {
        return (person =="physician")
      }))) with this: this.nurseListSpeciality2 = this.specialityTest.filter(
      person => {
        return (person =="physician")
      })

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168862/discussion-between-roli-roli-and-gileneusz).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vuejs 3 setup api and what you are trying to filter is from an external api call, consider appendding data after `.value`.

```
e.g specialityTest.value.data.filter(...)
```